# Hibernate Criteria returns duplicate entries ( No joins)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, sessionfactory

```
    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(ProductId.class);

    List<ProductId> policyCount2 = cr.list();
    System.out.println(policyCount2.size());

    for(ProductId x : policyCount2) {
        System.out.println(x.getPRODUCT_TEMPLATE_ID());
    }
```

there are 8 ProductId rows in the table.... Hibernate is able to find 8 records. however, it returns same product templates 8 times.. like this ...

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

This is a straight forward select from the table ProductId. there is no JOINS involved in this program.

Here is the ProductId template table

```
PRODUCT_ID  PRODUCT_TEMPLATE_ID
FDC140012   1
FDC140012   2
FDC140012   3
FDH140012   5
FDH140012   6
FDH140012   12
FDH140012   10
FDH140012   11
```

Here is the ProductId POJO...

```
public class ProductId {

private String PRODUCT_ID;
private int PRODUCT_TEMPLATE_ID;



public String getPRODUCT_ID() {
    return PRODUCT_ID;
}
public void setPRODUCT_ID(String pRODUCT_ID) {
    PRODUCT_ID = pRODUCT_ID;
}
public int getPRODUCT_TEMPLATE_ID() {
    return PRODUCT_TEMPLATE_ID;
}
public void setPRODUCT_TEMPLATE_ID(int pRODUCT_TEMPLATE_ID) {
    PRODUCT_TEMPLATE_ID = pRODUCT_TEMPLATE_ID;
}
public String getSTATE_LIST() {
    return STATE_LIST;
}
public void setSTATE_LIST(String sTATE_LIST) {
    STATE_LIST = sTATE_LIST;
}
}
```

Here is my Mapping file....

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.ProductId" table="PRODUCT_ID">
        <id name="PRODUCT_ID" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PRODUCT_ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="PRODUCT_TEMPLATE_ID" type="int">
            <column name="PRODUCT_TEMPLATE_ID" />
        </property>
        <property name="STATE_LIST" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="STATE_LIST" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Well, all must have the same PRODUCT_TEMPLATE_ID. Or your entity has a bug. Without seeing the data and the code, it's hard to explain. The fact that you have an ID of another entity is a smell: you should have an association instead. And of course, you should also respect the Java naming conventions in Java code, rather than the SQL naming conventions.

Comment: maybe because all the productId are linked to the same template (id 1)

Comment: I have pasted it above

Comment: @Gowtham Please, add `ProductId`

Comment: can you print x.getPRODUCT_ID() to see the retrieved products

Comment: Yes, the same product is retrieved.-  the product associated to 1

Comment: I debugged the code. The strange thing is - when I hovered over the list, the list has the SAME object 8 times, the hashcode number is the same ....

Comment: @Gowtham Please, add your mapping.

Comment: Here is my Mapping file....


<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.ProductId" table="PRODUCT_ID">
        <id name="PRODUCT_ID" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PRODUCT_ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="PRODUCT_TEMPLATE_ID" type="int">
            <column name="PRODUCT_TEMPLATE_ID" />
        </property>
        <property name="STATE_LIST" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="STATE_LIST" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

Comment: @Gowtham Where is `STATE_LIST` field? Please, add mapping to the question.

Comment: @Gowtham I update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you don't have an unique id. All `ProductId` have FDC140012 as `id`.

This means that you have only one column `PRODUCT_ID` as `id`.

```
<id name="PRODUCT_ID" type="java.lang.String">
  <column name="PRODUCT_ID" />
  <generator class="assigned" />
</id>
```

Hibernate gets all other objects from a cache.

Comment: i dont think so , there is another column called STATE_LIST which is also a PK.  I have a composite primary key ( PRODUCT_ID + STATE_LIST)

Comment: @Gowtham Why you don't have `STATE_LIST` in the `ProductId`.